# Check if png image is all transparent in golang

Tags: image, go

I have multiple urls like this one that always return a PNG image.

https://hydro.nationalmap.gov/arcgis/rest/services/wbd/MapServer/export?bbox=-106.6462299999999885,25.83722399999999908,-93.50780600000010168,36.50038700000000347&size=640,519&bboxSR=4326&layers=show:4&f=image&transparent=true

I want to check if the returned image from the url is all empty(transparent) like the above url or it has some actual image in there. I am making the request through below function and checking that the HTTP status is 200 and the returned content type is image. I need to add the functionality here to test if image is empty or not.

```golang
thumbnail := "https://hydro.nationalmap.gov/arcgis/rest/services/wbd/MapServer/export?bbox=-106.6462299999999885,25.83722399999999908,-93.50780600000010168,36.50038700000000347&size=640,519&bboxSR=4326&layers=show:4&f=image&transparent=true"

resp, err := client.Get(thumbnail)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
} else if resp.StatusCode == 200 && strings.HasPrefix(resp.Header["Content-Type"][0], "image") {
    return thumbnail
} else {
    fmt.Println(thumbnail, resp.StatusCode, resp.Header["Content-Type"][0])
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? Show your code. What research have you done into how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard library offers the capable `image` package and the `image/png` decoder that lets us do this quite easily.

We know that transparency means alpha=0, all we need to do is iterate through the image's pixels.

```
package main

import (
    "image/png"
    "io"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    transparentResp, _ := http.Get("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/3d/1_120_transparent.png")
    defer transparentResp.Body.Close()
    notTransparentResp, _ := http.Get("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/58/Pitch.png/640px-Pitch.png")
    defer notTransparentResp.Body.Close()
    println(isFullyTransparentPng(transparentResp.Body))
    println(isFullyTransparentPng(notTransparentResp.Body))
}

func isFullyTransparentPng(reader io.Reader) bool {
    img, _ := png.Decode(reader)
    for x := img.Bounds().Min.X; x < img.Bounds().Dx(); x++ {
        for y := img.Bounds().Min.Y; y < img.Bounds().Dy(); y++ {
            _, _, _, alpha := img.At(x, y).RGBA()
            if alpha != 0 {
                return false
            }
        }
    }
    return true
}
```